# How to compare time slot in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `[pricelist]`

```
startHour
endHour
Price
```

and another table that contains the `[actualuse]`

```
startDate
endDate
user
```

My data

`pricelist`:

```
startHour | endHour | price
----------------------------
00:00     | 07:59   | 10
08:00     | 15:59   | 20
16:00     | 23:59   | 5
```

`actualUse`:

```
startDate        | endDate         | jobId
-------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 08:30 | 12/10/2014 15:20| 1
12/10/2014 07:30 | 12/10/2014 18:20| 2
12/10/2014 07:30 | 13/10/2014 16:20| 3
12/10/2014 09:30 | 13/10/2014 00:20| 4
```

I try to get for every gob all rows in pricelist the are belong to. For example for jobId 1 I will get

```
startDate        | endDate         | jobId  |price
---------------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 08:30 | 12/10/2014 15:20| 1      |20
```

for jobId 2

```
startDate        | endDate         | jobId  |price
---------------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 07:30 | 12/10/2014 07:59| 2      |10    
12/10/2014 08:00 | 12/10/2014 15:59| 2      |20
12/10/2014 16:00 | 12/10/2014 18:20| 2      |5
```

for jobId 3

```
startDate        | endDate         | jobId  |price
---------------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 07:30 | 12/10/2014 07:59| 3      |10
12/10/2014 08:00 | 12/10/2014 15:59| 3      |20
12/10/2014 16:00 | 12/10/2014 23:59| 3      |5
13/10/2014 00:00 | 13/10/2014 07:59| 3      |10
13/10/2014 08:00 | 13/10/2014 15:59| 3      |20
13/10/2014 16:00 | 13/10/2014 16:20| 3      |5
```

Comment: The general solution is more complicated than you might think it is, because the prices could wrap around midnight.  This doesn't happen in your example, but it is a big complication.

Comment: there should a column for `join`

Comment: i don't think that is simple, i need to find all time slots in job . i need to create a calculate column for the join.

Comment: @eyalb For job 1, price is 20 not 10, right ?

Comment: Why data is repeated twice for job3?

Comment: @RezaRahmati because of the date range that contains two days

Comment: @GordonLinoff Maybe OP could accept a rule/limitation that startHour is always smaller than endHour in table priceList.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible working solution. I know the cursor is a bit ugly but I had to create another table with every possibles dates between the date ranges. You might be able to refactor some date computation too (I assumed you were working with `TIME` datatype)

```
/*
create table pricelist
(
    startHour time,
    endHour time,
    price decimal(18,2)
)

create table actualuse
(
    startDate datetime,
    endDate datetime,
    jobId int
)

insert pricelist values
('00:00','07:59',10),
('08:00','15:59',20),
('16:00','23:59',5)

set dateformat dmy
insert actualuse values
('12/10/2014 08:30','12/10/2014 15:20',1),
('12/10/2014 07:30','12/10/2014 18:20',2),
('12/10/2014 07:30','13/10/2014 16:20',3),
('12/10/2014 09:30','13/10/2014 00:20',4)

*/

BEGIN TRY DROP TABLE #actualUseDays END TRY
BEGIN CATCH END CATCH

CREATE TABLE #actualUseDays (
    startDate DATETIME
    ,endDate DATETIME
    ,jobId INT
    )

DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
    ,@endDate DATETIME
    ,@jobId INT;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT * FROM actualuse

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @startDate ,@endDate ,@jobId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT #actualUseDays
    SELECT @startDate
        ,iif(CAST(@endDate AS DATE) <> CAST(@startDate AS DATE), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', cast(@startDate AS DATE)), CAST(CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME) AS 
                    DATETIME2(7))), @endDate)
        ,@jobId

    UNION

    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number + 1, @startDate) AS DATE) [Date]
        ,iif(CAST(@endDate AS DATE) <> CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number + 1, @startDate) AS DATE), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number + 1, 
                            @startDate) AS DATE)), CAST(CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME) AS DATETIME2(7))), @endDate)
        ,@jobId
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(DAY, number + 1, CAST(@startDate AS DATE)) < @endDate

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @startDate ,@endDate ,@jobId
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

/*
#actualUseDays now contains : 

startDate               endDate                 jobId
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
2014-10-12 08:30:00.000 2014-10-12 15:20:00.000 1
2014-10-12 07:30:00.000 2014-10-12 18:20:00.000 2
2014-10-12 07:30:00.000 2014-10-12 23:59:59.000 3
2014-10-13 00:00:00.000 2014-10-13 16:20:00.000 3
2014-10-12 09:30:00.000 2014-10-12 23:59:59.000 4
2014-10-13 00:00:00.000 2014-10-13 00:20:00.000 4
*/

SELECT iif(CAST(a.startDate AS TIME) > p.startHour, startDate, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', CAST(startDate AS DATE)), CAST(startHour AS DATETIME2(7)))) AS 
    startDate
    ,iif(CAST(a.endDate AS TIME) < p.endHour, endDate, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', CAST(endDate AS DATE)), CAST(endHour AS DATETIME2(7)))) AS endDate
    ,jobId
    ,price
FROM #actualUseDays a
INNER JOIN pricelist p
    ON CAST(a.startDate AS TIME) <= p.endHour
        AND CAST(a.endDate AS TIME) >= p.startHour
ORDER BY jobId
    ,iif(CAST(a.startDate AS TIME) > p.startHour, startDate, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', CAST(startDate AS DATE)), CAST(startHour AS DATETIME2(7))))
```

Results :

```
startDate                   endDate                     jobId       price
--------------------------- --------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
2014-10-12 08:30:00.0000000 2014-10-12 15:20:00.0000000 1           20.00
2014-10-12 07:30:00.0000000 2014-10-12 07:59:00.0000000 2           10.00
2014-10-12 08:00:00.0000000 2014-10-12 15:59:00.0000000 2           20.00
2014-10-12 16:00:00.0000000 2014-10-12 18:20:00.0000000 2           5.00
2014-10-12 07:30:00.0000000 2014-10-12 07:59:00.0000000 3           10.00
2014-10-12 08:00:00.0000000 2014-10-12 15:59:00.0000000 3           20.00
2014-10-12 16:00:00.0000000 2014-10-12 23:59:00.0000000 3           5.00
2014-10-13 00:00:00.0000000 2014-10-13 07:59:00.0000000 3           10.00
2014-10-13 08:00:00.0000000 2014-10-13 15:59:00.0000000 3           20.00
2014-10-13 16:00:00.0000000 2014-10-13 16:20:00.0000000 3           5.00
2014-10-12 09:30:00.0000000 2014-10-12 15:59:00.0000000 4           20.00
2014-10-12 16:00:00.0000000 2014-10-12 23:59:00.0000000 4           5.00
2014-10-13 00:00:00.0000000 2014-10-13 00:20:00.0000000 4           10.00
```

Comment: look nice, but i working on mssql 2000, but the idea is the same, i will try to solve it

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that. I think you'll have to replace IIF with CASE WHEN and the CAST * AS DATE (to remove the time parts) to another convert